# bash заменить рекурсивно по регулярному выражению

Tags: bash

Пытаюсь заменить все совпадения строк на пустоту
все строки начинаются на `$a=` а заканчиваются на `}?>` между ними может быть любое количество любых символов (как я понимаю это *)
набросал вот такую команду, но видимо я не правильно составил регулярное выражение.

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/$a=*}?>/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, наверное, вот это имели в виду:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i -e "s/\\\$a=.*\\}\\?>//g"
```

Здесь:

- `\\\` означает первый `\\` экранирует символ в строке `\$`;
- `.` означает любой символ;
- `*` означает количество повторений от 0 до бесконечности;
- `\\` экранирует символы в строке `}` и `?`.

Пример:

```
% cat test.txt
---- начало файла -------
$a=         kjhkjgjhjhg    }?>
$a=   hgjg jgjh gjg jhg    }?>
$a=   g gh hgj hg jhg hg   }?>
---- конец файла --------

% find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i -e "s/\\\$a=.*\\}\\?>//g"

% cat test.txt
---- начало файла -------



---- конец файла --------
```